# Digital Ocean - It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, digital-ocean

For the last 2 days I've been trying to get my project to build on a DO App.
The funny thing is that nothing changed in the project and out of nowhere it suddenly started breaking with the error:

```
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │ It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │ 
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │ Please install typescript by running:
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │ 
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │         yarn add --dev typescript
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │ 
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │ If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
[2023-04-06 09:03:02] │
```

All we tried to do is restart (Force Redeploy and Build), and boom it started throwing this error.

At the same time our staging branch works just fine, the versions of packages are identical between the two.

```
 "dependencies": { 
    "next": "^12.0.7", 
    "react": "17.0.2", 
    "react-dom": "17.0.2", 
  },
  "devDependencies": { 
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.33", 
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3", 
  }
```

P.S. I have even tried to revert to an older working commit that was already deployed successfuly in the past and it too fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you probably set `NODE_ENV` manually to `production` in your env variables, this causes `yarn` to ignore your devDependencies and only install your main dependencies (hence why it cannot find typescript, which is usually installed as devDependency)

If you need a build time env var that lets your bundler know that it's a production environment, then I suggest using a different name like `APP_ENV` or something similar, so that yarn won't look at it and it will always include your devDependencies while building your app on DO App Platform.

For runtime instead you can use `cross-env` to set `NODE_ENV` to `production` in your start command.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the issue, took me 2-3 days to figure it out, I even forgot I asked a question here, but indeed, that is the problem and the fix was to remove the NODE_ENV.